# Error: Compile Error: Found punctuation symbol or operator '%' that isn't valid in Apex. at line 14 column 362

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, compile-error

```
global class ABI_SFA_TAC_Removal_Batch implements Database.batchable<sObject>
{    
    // variable decleration.
    public String Query;

     /* 
     Method Name: Start
     Description: This method is used to collect the TAC records ready for deletion.     
    */
    global Database.QueryLocator Start(Database.BatchableContext info)
    { 
       // fetch TAC records ready for removal.

        String Query = 'SELECT ABI_SFA_Account_Removal__c,ABI_SFA_Account__c,ABI_SFA_RecordID__c,ABI_SFA_SHAREID__c, ABI_SFA_Type__c,ABI_SFA_User__c,ABI_SFA_Valid_Till__c,CreatedById,CreatedDate,CurrencyIsoCode,Id,IsDeleted,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,Name,OwnerId,SystemModstamp FROM ABI_SFA_TerritoryAccountChange__c WHERE ABI_SFA_Account__r.name like '%Europromotion%' LIMIT 50000';

       return Database.getQueryLocator(query);  
    }

    /*
     Method Name: Execute
     Description: This method is used to process the TAC records that are passed from Start method.   
    */     
    global void Execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<ABI_SFA_TerritoryAccountChange__c> tacList)
    {
        if(tacList!=Null && tacList!=Empty){
            System.debug('@@@inside IF block');
            try {
                System.debug('@@@inside TRY block');
                Database.DeleteResult[] TAC_Dels = Database.delete(tacList);
            }
            catch (DmlException e) {
                System.debug('@@@ The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
                ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
                ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,<strong>string.valueof(e)</strong>); 
            }
        }
    }


    /*
     Method Name: Finish
     Description: This method is used to notify all relevant stakeholders via Email.      
    */       
    global void Finish(Database.BatchableContext info){ 

        String Email;
        List<ID> tacERId = new List<ID>();
        public void SendEmail() {
        for(TACEmailRecipients__c tacER: TACEmailRecipients__c.getAll().values());{
            tacERId.add(tacER.Id);
        }

        EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'TAC_Notification' limit 1];

        Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
        mail.setTargetObjectIds(tacERId);
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Acenture Support Team');
        mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] { mail });
}

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the single quotes after the like operator by using backslash character

```
 String Query = 'SELECT ABI_SFA_Account_Removal__c,ABI_SFA_Account__c,ABI_SFA_RecordID__c,ABI_SFA_SHAREID__c, ABI_SFA_Type__c,ABI_SFA_User__c,ABI_SFA_Valid_Till__c,CreatedById,CreatedDate,CurrencyIsoCode,Id,IsDeleted,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,Name,OwnerId,SystemModstamp FROM ABI_SFA_TerritoryAccountChange__c WHERE ABI_SFA_Account__r.name like '+'\'%Europromotion%\''+' LIMIT 50000';
```